# c++ string reading from file to vector string

Tags: c++, string, file, stl

> I want to read a text file which looks like below and 
>   put all those string into an array line by line to manipulate elements later use.
>   How can I do that ?

```
  TS1 24 12 apple
  TS2 24 15 strawberry banana kiwi
```

> if everything is okay, I want to access looks like

```
 str_arr1[0] = TS1, str_arr1[2] = 12
 s_array2[0] = TS2, s_array2[5] = kiwi
```

Comment: You are using the terms a bit wrong, an array has a fixed size, in the title you also speak of a vector.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline
...but you should be helped.
Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean what you say in the title *vector of string* and not array (fixed size), you can do this by using file stream `ifstream` and string stream.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


std::ifstream input_file;
    input_file.open("text_file.txt");
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> output_vector;
    while (getline(input_file, line))
    {
        std::istringstream ss_line(line);
        while(ss_line){
            std::string element;
            ss_line >> element;
            output_vector.push_back(element);
        }
    }
```

If you want a separate vector for each line, you can use an *vector of vectors of strings* instead, or if you know the amount of lines the file have, just declare that amount of vectors of strings.